# «Упорно не могу понять»

Tags: смысл, лексическая-сочетаемость

Что-то не так в этой фразе. С порядком слов, с сочетаемостью? Она — о чём?

Comment: "упорно не понимаю" = "несмотря ни на что не понимаю". "упорно не могу ..." = "несмотря ни на что не могу ...". "упорно не курю" = "несмотря ни на что не курю"

Comment: @user190920 Да нет. Нет такого значения в словарях. Здесь пропущен глагол: упорно пытаясь/стараясь, не могу понять. Упорно делаю = стараюсь сделать, упорно не делаю = стараюсь не сделать.

Comment: Чуть нагляднее, словарь Ефремовой: упорно=непреклонно. "упорно не могу ..." = "непреклонно не могу ..."="как меня ни клонят не могу ..."

Comment: Ничего от такой замены не проясняется. "Упорно не выполняю поручение" - имеет отрицательный смысл, следовательно, "упорно не могу" - тоже. Просто оно получило широкое распространение, поэтому типа звучит корректно.

Comment: Смотрите словарь Ефремовой, там прямая подстановка: упорно= 
не отступая от своего;

Comment: Для меня это очевидное _просторечие_, связанное с "проглатыванием" важного глагола от лености речи. Исходная фраза такова: "Упорно _пытаюсь_, но не могу понять". Выражение "в упор" (= оценивая с предельно близкого расстояния) далеко по смыслу от "упорства", но оно здесь более естественно.

Comment: @Alex_ander Согласен. Интересный момент: вроде как правильно "*от лености [ленивое отношение / склонность к лени] **в** речи*", потому что без **в** леность приобретает одушевлённость (как *леность человека*). Верно?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос задан неспроста. Думаю, что дело вот в чём.

Есть выражение "*в упор*" — в непосредственной близости к цели:
*В упор не вижу.

В упор не слышу.

В упор не понимаю.* || Сюда не подходит. Разве что в "сленговом стиле" норм.

И возможно, вместо него начали ошибочно употреблять "*упорно*". Так вот "*упорно не вижу*" и "*упорно не могу понять*" — этот тот же случай. Либо верны оба, либо ни один. Можно ли заменять "*в упор*" на "*упорно*"? Считаю, что нет, потому что такого значения нет в словарях.

"*Упорно не*" имеет значение отказа:
*Упорно не отвечаю на звонок.

Упорно не хожу на лекции.

Упорно не выполняю поручение.* || То есть упорно не делаю, отказываюсь что-то делать, а ещё лучше — упираюсь что-то делать. Это и есть значение "*не отступая от своего; упрямо*", указанное в словаре Ефремовой.
С "*не могу*" это значение не стыкуется. Это связано с тем, что это модальный глагол.
Модальные глаголы — это небольшая группа особых глаголов, которые не выражают действие или состояние, а отражают отношение говорящего к действию.

*Упорно делаю* = стараюсь сделать / делаю с упорством; *упорно не делаю* = стараюсь не сделать [отказываюсь] / с упорством не делаю это. Этот смысл очевиден, существует как факт. Кто не согласен? Он подходит под все корректные употребления. Подставляем:
*Стараюсь не смочь понять. => С упорством делаю так, чтоб не смочь понять.* || Нет, это не подходит.
Смысл скорее такой:
*В упор не могу понять.*  || Из-за схожести оригинальный вариант более-менее звучит.

Дело в том, что в данном случае имело место сокращение и пропущен глагол, к которому относится слово "*упорно*". А здесь нужно такое оформление мысли, чтоб было правильно:
*Упорно пытаюсь, но не могу понять.*

Если выражение корректно, то его можно употребить без "не":
*Упорно могу понять.* || Ерунда.
Ладно, если и этим не удаётся всех переубедить, то тогда вот что:
если выражение "*упорно не могу*" корректно, то "*упорно могу*" тоже должно иметь смысл, но его нет.

*Упорно/настойчиво рисовать = упорно делать так, чтоб нарисовать.

Упорно/настойчиво не рисовать = упорно делать так, чтоб не рисовать.

Упорно/настойчиво мочь => упорно делать так, чтоб смочь.* || Наперекор обстоятельствам. Проблемы с сочетаемостью из-за модальности: упорство [интенсивность] глагола "*мочь*" напрямую не зависит от человека (не получится слабее мочь или сильнее [упорнее] мочь). На это можно повлиять лишь другими действиями.
*Упорно/настойчиво не мочь => упорно делать так, чтоб не смочь.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127118/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).

Answer (score 2):

А мне кажется, что все хорошо в этой фразе.
Упорно — это наречие к прилагательному "упорный". Вот какие его значения есть в словаре русского языка (РАН, 1999):
[упорный](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
3. Проявляемый, обнаруживаемый постоянно, неизменно или с настойчивостью, упрямством. *Упорное молчание. Упорное **не**желание.* □ *Характерной чертой Ярмолы была упорная **не**словоохотливость* (А. И. Куприн. Олеся).

Если принять, что *упорно* = *неизменно*, то вырисовывается такая логическая цепочка:
упорное нежелание — упорно не желать — неизменно не желать (как бы ни уговаривали, как бы ни настаивали);
упорно не могу понять — неизменно не могу понять (как бы мне ни объясняли, как бы ни растолковывали, как бы ни комментировали, какие бы доводы ни приводили).

*Правда, пока я упорно не могу понять, почему меня не призывают* (М. Ильгова. Забвенье).

Comment: Упорно не желаю понять... Это буквально из песни «ничего не знаю — ничего никому не скажу. Тут детство или фанатизм, или хуже того — поза взрослого человека: типа «тупо не могу». Выставлять упрямство напоказ — ненормально. Потому и фраза нехорошая. «Пока я упорно не могу понять, почему меня не призывают», — не о понимании, а об информированности. Он не знает.

Comment: Здесь просторечие с пропуском элементов: *упорно делаю, но не могу сделать*. *Упорно* далеко по смыслу от *неизменно*. *Упорно не желать => упорно не хотеть желать; упорно не могу => упорно не хочу мочь* — не тот смысл получается.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу, о парадоксе парных слов.

*Упорно не вижу.* || Такое же просторечное сокращение (пропуск структурных элементов), как и в "*упорно не могу*".
Корректный вариант: *упорно стараюсь, но не вижу [отличие]*.

*Упорно не смотрю.* || Вот это уже корректно.
*Упорно стараюсь, но не смотрю.* || В отличие от предыдущего случая, это уже не подходит по смыслу, потому что "*упорно*" напрямую относится к глаголу.

То же и в случае пары *слышу/слушаю*:
*Упорно не слышу.* || Просторечный пропуск слов.
Корректный вариант: *упорно стараюсь, но не слышу [тональность песни]*.
*Упорно не слушаю.* || Корректно.

**Ключевым** является то, что если человек делает что-то упорно, то он **желает** это сделать, и даже очень желает, поэтому и проявляет рвение и настойчивость. В случае с "не" — не желает. Во фразе "*упорно не могу*" **никакого желания нет**.

Какой **вывод** из всего этого?

1. Если значение "*не получается что-то сделать*", то это просторечный пропуск слов, к которому все привыкли, поэтому оно звучит и кажется корректным. Но с точки зрения стилистики это далеко не так.
2. Корректно употребление с тем глаголом, с которым допустима форма меры и степени: *упорнее что-то делать*.

Update:
Возможно, что к исходной фразе ближе не "*упорно пытаюсь, но не могу понять*", а:
*Упорно происходит так, что не могу понять.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127177/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).

Answer (score 1):

[Словарь Ефремовой](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE)

```
Упорно:
 
Не отступая от своего;
```

Поэтому

```
Упорно не могу = Не отступая от своего не могу
```

Comment: Это смысл такой, но это не значит, что можно заменять. *Упорно занимаюсь на гитаре - не отступая от своего занимаюсь на гитаре.* Не подходит. Здесь значение "с упорством". Вот это значение истинное, на него можно везде заменить. Нет ни одного авторитетного примера (в том числе в словарях), где был бы глагол с частицей "не".

Comment: Упорно имеет несколько смыслов. В вашем примере замена не проходит, потому что у упорно другой смысл. А в моем примере подходит, потому что смысл такой же.

Comment: Там дано "упрямо" как синоним. Тогда: *упрямо не могу понять* - не подходит. *Упорно доказываю свою точку зрения* - это подходит. У вас не всё сходится.

Comment: "упрямо не могу понять" возможно, ибо синонимично "Не отступая от своего не могу понять ". Что и подтверждается словарем

Comment: Не согласен, звучит бредово. Давайте ещё хоть стилистику учитывать, а не лишь математически подставлять.

Comment: Истинный смысл при этом значении обратный: *не отступая от своего, не занимаюсь, не отступая от своего, не рисую* - то есть отказываюсь что-то делать. В случае с "не могу" этот истинный смысл не стыкуется, потому что "могу" - модальный глагол, он не выражает действия, а для корректного употребления слова "упорно" оно необходимо.

Comment: Прочитайте обновлённый ответ. Хоть вас удалось переубедить? Вы же всегда трезво мыслите...

Comment: Да меня не надо переубеждать, я просто набросил какую-то оригинальную идею для обогащения дискуссии. Это не значит, что я её придерживаюсь. Думаю, вы зря упираете на модальность. Скажем, "Упорно не понимаю" точно такое же "спорное", как и "Упорно не могу"

Comment: Да, такое же, потому что в том же несуществующем значении используется. Модальность точно не зря. Изначально просто хотел, чтоб была какая-то возможная сложная причина, которую не станут проверять, но потом убедился полностью. Оно не будет корректно работать с глаголами, в которых интенсивность действия не зависит от подлежащего. Человек либо может, либо нет, либо понимает, либо нет - он не может упорнее/усиленнее понимать, а может что-то сделать для того, чтоб лучше понять. То есть тоже признаки модальности. Не нахожу список всех русских модальных глаголов.

Comment: Третье слагаемое отброшено, почему-то... Есть понимание у говорящего, отчего он не может понять? Да, есть, — от своего предубеждения (не отступая от своего). Он его держится, или оно его, но суть: он не хочет понять, но прибегает к скользкой фразе с «не могу» и уходит от прямого разговора.