# «Упорно слышу в ответ одно и то же». Грамотна ли фраза?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как вы считаете, грамотна ли фраза на 100%? Или полный бред?

```
Упорно слышу в ответ одно и то же.
```

Я думаю, грамотна на 100%, а вот *@oledd* утверждает, что полный бред.
Разрешите наш спор (он здесь: [«Упорно не могу понять»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466849/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)).

Comment: Тут скорее *упорно отвечают одно и то же*, а не *упорно слышу одно и то же*.

Comment: Упорно можно только _сл**у**шать_ (осознанное действие, совершаемое _с упорством_, усилием или упрямством). Нельзя упорно слышать, мочь или не мочь. А вот "в упор" (с близкого расстояния) не слышать, конечно, можно.

Comment: @user190920 Даже "*Упорно получаю один и тот же ответ.*” является некорректным с точки зрения логики, несмотря на стилистическую сочетаемость (упорно получать — возможно).

Comment: Логику я вам любую придумаю, будет корректно. Лишь бы была база примеров и люди договорились. Вот об этом и вопрос. В гугле тысячи примеров типа "упорно встречаю", "упорно сталкиваюсь" итп, но как эти примеры воспринимаются на слух, а не на логику. А за логикой дело не встанет.

Comment: "Упорно получать" возможно говорите? А чем это отличается от "упорно получать одно и то же"?

Comment: Уже 2 раза отвечал. Например, второй комментарий. А ранее приводил в пример ситуацию с корректным употреблением. В Гугле такое можно найти, что и прочитать сложно, в гугл-книгах в том числе.

Comment: Вы хоть сами перечитайте свой второй комментарий, там совсем о другом. упорно отвечают, а не упорно получают.

Comment: Там об этом же. Тут скорее *упорно отвечают одно и то же*, а не *упорно получаю одно и то же*. Он просто получает, без упорства. А теперь сравните эти комментарии — разница в один глагол, можно было и уловить.

Comment: Ах вот что имеется в виду. Другое значение глагола получать=добывать. Ну тогда и "с упорством получаю(добываю) один и тот же ответ" тоже возможно, только контекст немного сюрреальный.

Comment: *С упорством получаю письмо* — должен быть весьма экзотический контекст: *почта закрывается, просят на выход, в всё равно упорно получаю письмо*. И да, в корректных примерах замена на "с упорством" корректна, потому что очевидно, что "упорно работаю" = "работаю с упорством". С другими глаголами то же. "Получать=добывать" — не всегда, имеется в виду "изготавливать".

Comment: Что насчет: "Я без упорства не способен понять, и даже с упорством не способен тоже"?

Comment: Всё верно. Вывод: вовсе не способен понять, и от упорства это не зависит.

Comment: Тогда почему вы отрицаете фразу "Я упорно не могу понять", ведь после замены это "Я с упорством не способен понять"

Comment: *Не могу* и *не способен* — очень разные вещи. Второе — не глагол.

Comment: Что насчет: "Я без упорства не имею возможности понять, и даже с упорством не имею возможности тоже"?

Comment: Стилистика "без упорства не имею возможности" очень плохая, так люди не говорят. Но со структурой порядок. Обратите внимание, что в данных примерах "с упорством" не примыкает к глаголу, потому что "не имею возможности" = "нет возможности". Ваши действия сейчас абсолютно напоминают ситуацию, когда через делание на 0 доказали, что 3 = 5. Но подобной хитростью меня не проведёшь.

Comment: Извините, это вы пытаетесь делить на ноль заменами в духе "не имею возможности" = "нет возможности". В русском языке есть глагол либо его нет. Третьего не дано, и не надо проводить замены, ведь это "очень разные вещи. Второе — не глагол"

Comment: Более того, в этих примерах "с упорством" уже не обстоятельство, заменяемое на "упорно", а добавление (вопросы: *без чего? даже с чем?*).

Comment: Это детерминантное (слабопримыкающее) обстоятельство. Можно спросить у знатоков. Пример такой "Я не имею возможности понять никоим образом, ни с упорством, ни без.

Comment: Стилистически корректно: *не было возможности понять*. Но тогда кто-то мешал понять, а иначе нужно "не мог понять". Интересный факт: *с упорством не могу* — корректно. Вы же этого пытаетесь сейчас добиться? Просто пропущено существительное: *с упорством в действиях не могу*. Ну а кто запрещает пропускать? Структура от этого не страдает, в отличие от "упорно не могу".

Comment: Просто в вашем предыдущем примере вопрос *как?* не подходит., особенно для "без упорства". Там прямо просится *без чего? с чем?* Мне кажется, что оно в некоторых случаях бывает обстоятельством, а в некоторых — дополнением.

Comment: @oleedd [Я просто оставлю это здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94aXgvaGVyemVuL2J5bG9lNS54bWw%3D&dpp=5&format=html&g=i_doc&kwsz=5&lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&out=normal&req=%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5&sampling=1&sort=i_grtagging&spd=10&spp=50&sr=1&text=lexform). На самом деле считаю, что хотя и не очень логичное, но уже допустимое выражение: упорство здесь, скажем так, метафорическое.

Comment: @creativecommas На самом деле в Нацкорпусе куча ошибок (это довольно известный факт). Он больше для частотности: что чаще употребляется, то и корректнее.

Comment: @oleedd я знаю, но я просто привела самый старый встретившийся пример, чтобы показать, что это не неологизм. А вообще в корпусе несколько сотен вхождений с "упорно не", и очень многие примеры - как раз с использованием по сути пассивных глаголов (видеть, понимать, замечать, осознавать и т. д.)

Comment: @creativecommas Да, реально очень старый пример. Допустимое опять же в разговорной речи — лишь потому, что понятен смысл. Чуть похоже на фразеологизм — из-за того, что значения слов не складываются. Но у фразеологизмов нет ассортимента глаголов. Это "разговорный хак". В таких случаях корректно использовать "в упор": *в упор не вижу / не понимаю*.

Comment: @oleedd Соглашусь, что выглядит как артефакт разговорной речи; но мне кажется, что это уже очень плотно вошло в обиход. Как редактор я бы не стала в тексте помечать это в качестве ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Если мнение некого oleedd - единственный аргумент вашего внутреннего оппонента, можете смело им пренебречь. Тем более, что оно, мнение, вами не представлено.

А мое мнение (которым вы тоже вправе пренебречь) таково: до стопроцентной грамотности немного не дотягивает. Наречие "упорно" здесь не к месту. У него нет подходящего значения. Было бы "постоянно" - все было бы ОК.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза хотя логически и не верна, но весьма точна по передаче смысла ситуации. Сразу понятно, что человек много раз получает один и тот же ответ, который его коробит / не удовлетворяет / который он не хотел бы получать :)

Comment: Вот даже мысли не было о таком понимании.

Comment: @user190920 вы именно такой смысл вкладываете во фразу? Или хотя бы что-то напоминающее?