# Оба варианта составления предложения верны?

Tags: синтаксис

Вариант 1: Работал на предприятиях общественного питания заведующим кондитерским цехом, заведующим торговой группой и заведующим производством.

Вариант 2: Работал заведующим кондитерским цехом, заведующим торговой группой и заведующим производством на предприятиях общественного питания.

Оба варианта корректны?

Comment: На мой взгляд, оба корректны, но первый лучше, потому что однозначно считывается, что все эти должности он занимал, работая на предприятиях общественного питания. Во втором варианте возможны трактовки относительно того, к чему относится "на предприятиях общественного питания" -- ко всем должностям или только к последней.

Comment: @shampar, укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки.

Comment: О согласовании и управлении речь. А вообще, хорошо знать, в чём проблема-то.

Comment: @shampar, если бы я мог что-то проверить самостоятельно, то смысл задавать вопрос здесь? У меня есть два варианта предложения, которые я смог придумать. Но у меня, как человека далекого от филологии, возникли сомнения в том, какой вариант, так сказать, более верный. Поэтому, если у Вас есть какие-то возражения против ответа creativecommas, то прошу просто и доходчиво донести это до меня.

Comment: @creativecommas такие комментарии лучше публиковать в виде ответа. Не стесняйтесь отвечать.

Comment: Я не была уверена в своем заявлении, поэтому ответила в комментарии. Простите, я новичок здесь, пока не до конца поняла, как всё работает. Отвечая @shampar - упорно не вижу ошибок, если не считать повтора слова "заведующий", но этот повтор во многом оправдан. Могу только предположить, что вы считаете, что нужно говорить "заведующий цеха", а не "заведующий цехом", но это ошибочно.

Comment: @creativecommas *упорно не вижу ошибок* — фразы такого типа обсуждались [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466849) и [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466871). Должно быть интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, оба корректны, но первый лучше, потому что однозначно считывается, что все эти должности он занимал, работая на предприятиях общественного питания. Во втором варианте возможны трактовки относительно того, к чему относится "на предприятиях общественного питания" — ко всем должностям или только к последней.

Не очень удачен повтор слова "заведующий", предложу альтернативный вариант, чтобы избавиться от повторов:

(факультативно: В разное время) *Руководил* (вариант: заведовал) *различными подразделениями на предприятиях общественного питания:  кондитерским цехом, торговой группой, производством.*

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант: *Работал на предприятиях общественного питания в должности заведующего, — кондитерским цехом, торговой группой, производством*.

Comment: Нет, так нельзя, там разные должности, а не заведующий всем этим сразу.

Comment: http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_32

Comment: Спасибо,  oleedd

Answer (score 0):

Если указывать на ошибки, то одна есть. В первом варианте, после слова «питания» следует поставить двоеточие.
«§ 159. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, которым заканчивается предложение:

1. Если перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово … (в Вашем случае могло быть «в качестве: заведующего кондитерским цехом…»)
2. Если перед перечислением нет обобщающего слова, но необходимо предупредить читателя, что далее следует какой-либо перечень, например: Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и еще кой-какие привлекательные узелки и коробочки. Л. Толстой»

Кроме того, оба варианта содержат стилистическую погрешность – повторы слова «заведующий».
Следовало использовать синонимы слова «заведующий», коих множество: руководитель, начальник, управляющий, ведущий, глава, директор, командир, шеф, ответственный за…

Предлагается вариант 3:  Работал на предприятиях общественного питания: начальником кондитерского цеха, руководителем торговой группы и заведующим производством.

Comment: Двоеточие в первом предложении возможно, но совсем не обязательно. Это зависит от того, хочет ли автор сделать акцент на "предприятиях общественного питания", или хочет просто перечислить должности. Вариант "работал на предприятиях **в качестве**: заведующего... шефа и т. д." совсем плохой, канцелярский. А вот предложение заменить "заведующего" синонимами разумно, но вряд ли применимо в данной ситуации - автору, похоже, важно указать именно названия должностей.