# Деепричастный оборот при перечислении

Tags: перечисление

Я правильно понимаю, что в нижеприведённом тексте, ограничения касаются только тех, кто использует этот налоговый режим?  Т.е. идёт перечисление таких лиц, а остальных это не касается, если у них другой налоговый режим?

Кое-кто уверяет, что этот деепричастный оборот относится только к "физическим лицам", а я не согласен. Считаю, что он относится ко всем перечисленным. Кто прав?
Текст:
Установить, что в период нерабочих дней с 28 октября по 8 ноября 2021 года включительно приостанавливается доступ посетителей и работников в здания, строения, сооружения (помещения в них), на территории, в которых (на которых) юридическими лицами, индивидуальными предпринимателями,  физическими лицами, применяющими специальный налоговый режим "на профессиональный доход" (далее - организации), осуществляется реализация товаров, выполнение работ, оказание услуг.

Answer (score 1):

Оборот не деепричастный (*применяя*), а причастный (*применяющие*).

Раз верно "на территориях", а не "в территориях", то и верно "на которых" (а не "в которых").

Пример:
*У меня есть яблоки, персики и сливы, купленные на рынке.* || Купленные на рынке только сливы или всё? **Может быть и так и так.**

Здесь вопрос в том, кто может применять этот специальный налоговый режим. Все или только последние.

> Считаю, что он относится ко всем перечисленным.

Скорее всего, так и есть. В деловом стиле бы использовался разграничитель:
*Установить, что в период нерабочих дней с 28 октября по 8 ноября 2021 года включительно приостанавливается доступ посетителей и работников в здания, строения, сооружения, на территории, **на** которых юридическими лицами, индивидуальными предпринимателями, **а также** физическими лицами, применяющими специальный налоговый режим "на профессиональный доход" (далее — организации), осуществляется реализация товаров, выполнение работ, оказание услуг.*

Небольшим разграничителем является даже союз И, хоть и при нём возможны варианты, с ним вероятность того, что относится ко всему, меньше. Во всех стилях при отнесении только к последнему, если возможно отнесение ко всему, обычно используется разграничитель либо меняется порядок слов (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467903) пример), чтобы устранить двусмысленность, которая подобна стилистической ошибке. Особенно это важно для делового стиля — чтобы не было несколько интерпретаций, от чего люди могут финансово пострадать.